# How to use NFS mounted storage as particular user

Tags: linux, mount, nfs, redhat-enterprise-linux

I have a NFS storage where I want to create and modify files from my local machine. On that NFS server there is a user with a group. But when I write a file from some local application to that storage, that file has a different user belonging to a different group. How can I force my local application to pretend to be the user from the NFS machine?

This also causes trouble when I want to modify existing files - I don't have write permissions...

Answer (score 1):

The NFS server maps the users based on their uid and gid, not on their names. So if a user has a same name on the client side and on the server side, but different uid's, you end up with this kind of problems. There exists solutions to completely redefine the mapping, but doesn't seem to be easy (and I can't help). However, in the context of a single user there is an easy solution: map **all** the client side users to a single user on the server side. This is achieved with the `all_squash` export option, together with `anonuid=` and `anongid=` to specify the target user on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

You have to force on the server side.
On the exports file you have to specify anonuid=xxxx,anongid=xxxx on the option of the directory exports.
Replace xxxx with server userid (anonuid) and server groupid (anongid)

omar

Comment: Setting `anonuid` and `anongid` will just map the client root user to the specified server user.